# php, get values from matrix (array)

Tags: php

I have Matrix and how get value from there?
The data obtained from a file, so that the matrix can be of different sizes

Thanks

Comment: A sample of your loading code would be nice.

Comment: Are you talking about a two dimensional array in PHP?  If you clarify your question we won't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothetically (because the question is vague), if you read the contents in and have the results stored in a two-dimensional array, then you would use brackets to find the cell value. For example, here's reading in the contents into a multidimensional array called $matrix:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("myfile.csv");
$splitlines = explode("\n",$contents);//split the contents into rows
$matrix = array();
foreach($splitlines as $line){
    $row = explode(",",$line);//split each line into columns
    $matrix[] = $row;//add the array of columns as a new row in the matrix
}
```

now address any of the values in the matrix:

```
$samplevalue = $matrix[2][1]; //addresses the third row, second column.
```